# button created programmatically doesn't respond to target, swift

Tags: swift, button, header, tableview, frame

I'm creating a button in my tableView header in section 1.

I do it like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    if section == 1 {
        var button   = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        header.addSubview(button)
    }
        return header
}

 func Action(sender: UIButton){
    println("button was pressed")
}
```

The button appears in section 1 only (as it should)  but if I press on it instead of printing the message, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I wasn't specifying the button.frame correctly. Since the button was outside the frame, it was never called.

```
 button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, tableView.frame.size.width - 5, 18);
```